# Does the iPhone OS4 API do this? (bluetooth)

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch

- get an array of bluetooth ID's
- Broadcast the bluetooth signal manually

Comment: Anyone who has a copy of the iPhone SDK 4 Beta is legally prohibited from discussing its features by the associated non-disclosure agreement (NDA).

Comment: @Adam: Please don't just invent tags that don't categorize the question itself.

Comment: @Georg: it perfectly categorised the question and all like it which are about items under NDA. Instead of countless responses "well that is under NDA..." just apply the tag.

Comment: @Adam: Commenting, vote-to-close, or in extremer cases flag-for-moderation, are the tools - tags are not to categorize for *"shouldn't be here"* or to describe a temporary property of the question. There are e.g. no `[belongs-on-*]` on SO anymore.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No. You still cannot control bluetooth directly for AppStore apps.

Comment: Thanks. Can you provide a source?

Comment: @alex: There's no source for something that does not exist.

Comment: @alex: Read the documentation around the External Accessories framework for more on communicating with external Bluetooth hardware.